# Convert lowercase to uppercase in a string

Tags: c++, string

> The new typist in the printing cell is typing carelessly the jobs assigned. The typist while was supposed to type all the characters in upper case, has got in lower cases too. Your duty is to verify if all the characters are in upper case and do so if not. Also, notify how many mistakes the typist did.
>
> Input `bEGIN`
>
> Output `BEGIN 1`

I am getting wrong answer in some of the cases please help i am beginner

> n=length of string
> 1<=n<=50

```
 int main() {
     
     string s;
     cin >> s;
     int ans = 0;
     for (auto &c : s) {
         if (islower(c)) {
             ans++;
             c = toupper(c);
         }
     }
     cout << s;
     cout << endl;
     cout << ans;
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can input contain space? if so use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `operator >>`.

Comment: For some specific input, what is the expected output? What is the actual output of your program? And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: what was the input for which you are getting wrong answer?

Comment: `I am getting wrong answer in some of the cases.` Can you give an example?

Comment: According to you, output of `bEGIN` is `BEGIN 1`. If that's the case, observe that you're printing `ans` in next line instead of the same line. Use `cout<<s<<" "<<ans;`

Comment: For an idiomatic C++ solution, please read about [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), and [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). Those three functions  (with the help of `std::islower` and `std::toupper`) will do all you want in a compact but still understandable way.

Comment: Hey @beginner can you see in which format output needs to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it includes spaces too, so instead of using `>>` operator use `getline(cin,string)`, as `>>` gets terminate when whitespace is occurred.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

 string s;
 getline(cin,s);
 int ans = 0;
 for (auto &c : s) {
     if (islower(c)) {
         ans++;
         c = toupper(c);
     }
 }
 cout << s;
 cout << endl;
 cout << ans;
 return 0;
}
```

This might be a solution to other test cases.

Comment: Not return exactly, but when whitespace occurred, std:cin >> doesn't store further values.

Comment: @ArminMontigny : [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) not mentioned ill effect as you noted above

Comment: Moreover, islower() can handle alphanumerics character, I think there is some other corner case that we haven't given a thought.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


 int main() {

     string s;
    getline(cin,s);
     int ans = 0;
     for (auto &c : s) {
         if (islower(c)) {
             ans++;
             c = toupper(c);
         }
     }
     cout << s;
     cout << endl;
     cout << ans;
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Except for the two includes this answer is identical to the other one. Except that the other answer actually offers an explanation of the possible problem. So why do you post it again?